# Tiled Vector Based Map iOS

Tags: ios, vector, maps, vector-graphics

I am attempting to create a custom vector based map using tiles, much like iOS 6 Maps. I have seen many great solutions for raster-based maps, but so far nothing based on Vector Based Maps.

I have the entire map in drawing code, but unfortunately it is too big to use in one file. I also have the svg. preferably, i would like a solution that does not involve recreating the entire map in another format, yet also, i would prefer if the solution was easy on the iPhone, ie did not crash/perform slowly on it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for your kind assistance,

Comment: In what sense is the drawing code too big for one file? You mean that if you just execute it without modification then it takes too long to process or you've hit some sort of file size bug with the tools?

Comment: the code generated is 10,000,000+ characters, Xcode will just freeze up on compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to output the SVG as a [vector] PDF. That should be something you can achieve automatically using whatever software you used to create the SVG. The advantage of PDF is that it's a vector format that iOS natively understands and can render in a small number of calls.

What you then probably want to do is create a subclass of UIView that can render the PDF. You'll need to drop down to the [relevant Core Graphics C stuff](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html) but it's not all that difficult to achieve. Pulling a tutorial off the internet at random gives me [this one](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/).

If you give that UIView a `layerClass` of `CATiledLayer` then size it for the whole of your map and place it inside a scroll view you should get the exact same tiling behaviour as Maps, Safari, etc. You won't have to implement anything special — if you trap your view's `drawRect:` you should see it being called just for small sections.

Don't worry about any older tutorials on `CATiledLayer` that start raising threading concerns — per [QA1637](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1637/_index.html) you're permitted just to implement drawRect: in the normal UIKit way and have the threading just work since iOS 4. Assuming you intend to support the iPhone 5 screen resolution you can't submit for older than 4.3 anyway and even if you aren't then I really don't recommend you expend the effort.